# window.onresize

Tags: javascript

Скажите пожалуста как сделать чтоб window.onresize работал только на одной странице а не на всех?

Comment: Не добавлять обработчик этого события на тех страницах, где он не нужен?

Comment: Ну или запихать обработчик в условие `if(location.href === 'https://mysite.com/page.htm') {...}`